# Why is my jQuery Progress Bar Missing a Segment?

Tags: jquery, html, progress-bar

I have the following HTML/jQuery code to show a progress bar with 3 segments, each a different colour:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" role="progressbar" style="width: @(Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsTechnical)%;" title="@("Segment: 'Tech'" + Environment.NewLine + "Value: " + Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsTechnical)"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width: @(Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsManagement)%;" title="@("Segment: 'Man'" + Environment.NewLine + "Value: " + Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsManagement)"></div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning" role="progressbar" style="width: @(Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsQuality)%;" title="@("Segment 'Qual'" + Environment.NewLine + "Value: " + Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsQuality)"></div>
    <div style="padding-top: 3px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;@Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsTotal.ToString("N2")</div>
</div>
```

Now the bar is rendered as follows:

[image]

Where `Blue` corresponds to `PointsTechnical`, with a value of `44`, then `Orange` to `PointsQuality`, with a value of `4`. The total, `71.5`, includes `PointsManagement`, which has a value of `23.5`, and should correspond to `Green`.

Why is `Green`, or `PointsManagement`, missing from my progress bar?

Comment: which `jQuery` / `Bootstrap` Versions are used?

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output to ensure the `width` of each segment is being set as you expect it to be?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @freedomn-m No, it's 44 (blue, shown), + 4 (orange, shown), then 23.5  (green, _not shown_), giving a total of 71.5 (text, shown). I said the total includes green, not that it _is_ green.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, I hadn't, thank you. I found out that with my IIS settings, `style="width: @(Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsManagement)%;"` was rendering as `style="width: 71,5%;"`, with a comma for the decimal separator. Of course CSS doesn't understand the comma so any segment of my progress bar that had a decimal fraction wouldn't show.

Comment: Glad you found the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @RoryMcCrossan's suggestion in comments that I check the HTML output. I found that:

```
style="width: @(Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsManagement)%;"
```

was rendering as:

```
style="width: 71,5%;"
```

with a comma for the decimal separator. Of course CSS doesn't understand the comma so any segment of my progress bar that had a decimal fraction wouldn't show.

I changed my code to read

```
style="width: @(Model.TendersReceived[i].PointsManagement.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))%;"
```

and the progress bar/graph is working fine.